# Efficient way to lookup in a data frame in R

Tags: r, performance, lookup

Well maybe it was stupid of me to have Dog, fish and horse as an example.
What if I have Location instead, i.e. and the index is where in location 1, 2 and 3 they are located or something else. Horse 1 can be at location 2 and 3

```
index    |Location 1|Location 2|Location 3|...                        
1        |Dog1      |Horse1    |Fish1   |
2        |Horse3    |Fish2     |Horse1  |
3        |Fish2     |Horse2    |Horse3  |
4        |Dog1      |Fish1     |Horse2  |
5        |...       |...       |...     |...
```

Then i want to quickly look up my data.frame and find all the index values. I wish to build a dictionary of location 1, location 2 and location 3. Then I can just type locatio1['dog1'] and get all the index values of dog1 in location 1.

In python i would have build a dictionary of location1 and have

```
location1_dict = {dog1 : [1, 4], Horse3 : [2], Fish2 : [3]}
```

and the same for `location2_dict` and so on.

Anyway, is there an efficient way in r to lookup a data.frame quickly. Imagine that I have 10^6 rows

Comment: Try `df$index[df$Location1 == "dog1"]`, assuming that your look up table is `df`

Comment: What you want in R is a list ("thedictionary") containing a list for each location, and each of those containing named vectors of index values (named like each existing value in the existing location columns). Then you will be able to get the info you want by calling `thedictionary$location1$dog` etc. Use the `which()` function to get the index of each value in each location. Then you need two nested for loops or perhaps the `purrr::map`* category functions.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to get the index values and then `lapply` it to the columns of interest.

```
locations <- function(x){
  y <- unique(x)
  sapply(y, grep, x, , ignore.case = TRUE, simplify = FALSE)
}

res <- lapply(df1[-1], locations)

str(res)
#List of 3
# $ Location.1:List of 3
#  ..$ Dog1  : int [1:2] 1 4
#  ..$ Horse3: int 2
#  ..$ Fish2 : int 3
# $ Location.2:List of 4
#  ..$ Horse1: int 1
#  ..$ Fish2 : int 2
#  ..$ Horse2: int 3
#  ..$ Fish1 : int 4
# $ Location.3:List of 4
#  ..$ Fish1 : int 1
#  ..$ Horse1: int 2
#  ..$ Horse3: int 3
#  ..$ Horse2: int 4
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(index = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Location.1 = c("Dog1", 
"Horse3", "Fish2", "Dog1"), Location.2 = c("Horse1", "Fish2", 
"Horse2", "Fish1"), Location.3 = c("Fish1", "Horse1", "Horse3", 
"Horse2")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```